# How to find the most popular word in the text in a text file through the linux terminal

Tags: terminal, search, text

How to find the most popular word in a text file through the linux terminal?
Need to write a script

Comment: Use sed, sort, uniq, head commands.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/661661/listing-all-words-in-a-text-file-and-finding-the-most-frequent-word

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered many times, please use search next time.

```
tr -c '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' < test.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```